# can't insert lots of registers to my DB

Tags: php, insert

I am inserting many registers at the same time in the BD. First he gave me the error Fatal Error: Maximum Execution Time of x seconds Exceeded. I managed to eliminate this error by changing the max_execution_time variable from 30 to 300 in the php.ini file. Now I do not know what error it shows me but the die tells me there is an error.

How can I know what is the error that is happening?

The code is:

```
<?php

$fichero = "./obras.xml";
if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($fichero))
{
    echo "No se ha podido cargar el archivo <br>";
} 
else 
{
    echo "El archivo se ha cargado correctamente <br>";
}

include"./conectar.php";
$enlace= conectarse();

function limpia_espacios($cadena){
    $cadena = str_replace(' ', '', $cadena);
    return $cadena;
}


function Mayus($variable) {
$variable = strtr(strtoupper($variable),"àèìòùáéíóúçñäëïöü","ÀÈÌÒÙÁÉÍÓÚÇÑÄËÏÖÜ");
return $variable;
}

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

foreach ($xml as $obra)
{
    $obra = (array) $obra;
    $ninv = $obra['ninventario'] . '/' . $obra['ncatalogo'];
    $dimen = limpia_espacios($obra['medidas_con_marco']);

    $ninv = Mayus($ninv);
    $contrato = Mayus($obra['contrato']);
    $desc = Mayus($obra['titulo']);
    $tecnica = Mayus($obra['tecnica']);
    $pieza = Mayus($obra['tipo']);
    $lochab = Mayus($obra['localizacion_habitual']);
    $ubicacion = Mayus($obra['ultima_localizacion']);


    $consulta ="INSERT INTO `bcficha` (`ninv`, `contrato`, `desc`, `tecnica`, `pieza`, `dimen`, `lochab`, `ubicacion`) VALUES ('".$ninv."','".$contrato."','".$desc."','".$tecnica."','".$pieza."','".$dimen."', '".$lochab."', '".$ubicacion."')"; 

    $resultado = mysql_query($consulta) or die("error mysql"); 

}


?>
```

And in the broser i read this:

> El archivo se ha cargado correctamente
>
> Conectado !!!
>
> error mysql

**mysql error is written by the die function when executing the query**

I'm thinking about putting a counter because I know it stops at 582, and modify the script so that it goes to 583 and starts inserting from this

thank you very much

PD:

I used die (mysql_error ()) to know the error that was happening and I get the following: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ANGEL', 'OIL', 'PAINT', '74x131', 'R45', 'R45') 'at line 1. Could it be that there is some character in the XML file that comes into conflict with the SQL file?

Comment: you can check for mysql_error();  to get a text error represemtation of the problem. It may be query too long.

Comment: Look into using prepared statements and bind variables, this will help with performance and may solve errors where strings contain quotes.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi how i can check mysql_error(). I think it's a too long query

Comment: @NigelRen I do not understand what you mean, I do not take much time programming in php, can you give me an example?

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-param-examples - NOTE that this uses mysqli - looks as though your using mysql_ (which is deprecated in later versions of PHP).

Comment: swap die('mysql error') with die(mysql_error())

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi i edit the question with the error

Comment: According to that error, you should use escaping for your values. There might be a single quote somewhere in your values causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the XML file there are characters like that, and when doing the insert in PHP there is a conflict with that character

Comment: since you are using an old mysql deprecated tech, and that you should know that you may have serious sql injection risks, at this point you can add mysql_add_slashes() or whatever is written your fields.